# TypeScript: type-safe class decorator that handles static methods?

Tags: typescript

How can I write a type-safe class decorator that correctly handles static methods?

Specifically, this decorator will work for classes *without* static methods:

```
interface ITypeOf<T> {
    new(...args: any[]): T
}

function decorate<T>(cls: ITypeOf<T>): ITypeOf<T> {
    return cls
}
```

But `ITypeOf` doesn't consider static attributes, so the compile fails with this error when it's applied to a class with static attributes:

```
@decorate
class Foo {
    static bar() {
        return 42
    }
}
```

Yields the error:

```
Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
  Type 'ITypeOf<Foo>' is not assignable to type 'typeof Foo'.
    Property 'bar' is missing in type 'ITypeOf<Foo>'.
function decorate<T>(cls: ITypeOf<T>): ITypeOf<T>
```

Here's a working example: 
[http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface…](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ITypeOf%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20decorate%3CT%3E(cls%3A%20ITypeOf%3CT%3E)%3A%20ITypeOf%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20cls%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Note%20the%20error%20here%3A%20%22'bar'%20is%20missing%20from%20ITypeOf%3CFoo%3E%22%0D%0A%2F%2F%20How%20can%20I%20write%20a%20generic%20class%20decorator%20that%20can%20handle%0D%0A%2F%2F%20static%20methods%3F%0D%0A%40decorate%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20bar()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%2042%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

How can I write a type-safe class decorator that works for classes with static members?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type of the decorator must be compatible with the class type it is decorating as the return value of the decorator will replace the class at runtime. To achieve this, we must use a generic parameter representing the class itself, that will be both the type of the parameter and the return type. We will thus be returning a class with the same structure as the input class (including the statics) and the compiler will be satisfied:

```
function decorate<TCtor extends ITypeOf<any>>(cls: TCtor): TCtor {
    return cls
}

@decorate
class Foo {
    static bar() {
        return 42
    }
}
```

To add restrictions on the class to be decorated we can be more restrictive of the type parameter to `ITypeOf`:

```
// decorated class must have a field x: numeber
function decorate<TCtor extends ITypeOf<{ x: number }>>(cls: TCtor): TCtor {
    return cls
}

@decorate // error no instance x
class Foo { }
@decorate // ok
class Boo { x!: number }
```

We can also add restrictions as to static members

```
// decorated class must have a static field x: numeber
function decorate<TCtor extends ITypeOf<any> & { x: number }>(cls: TCtor): TCtor {
    return cls
}

@decorate // error no static x
class Foo { }
@decorate // ok
class Boo { static x: number }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I write a type-safe class decorator that works for classes
>   with static members?

It depends on what are you going to do inside the decorator.

You can simply have `decorator` completely generic like this:

```
function decorate<C>(cls: C) {
    return cls;
}
```

However this does not capture any information about `C`, so you can't do much with `cls` inside `decorate`.

Or you can have separate generic parameters, one for the "instance side" of `cls` and another one for the "static side":

```
interface ITypeOf<T> {
    new(...args: any[]): T
}

function decorate<I, S extends ITypeOf<I>>(cls: S): S {
    return cls
}


@decorate
class Foo {
    static bar() {
        return 42
    }

}
```

Comment: I considered the two parameter approach but I am not sure what value it adds. If you need the instance type inside the decorator you can use `InstanceType` and for restricting the decorated class restricting the argument to `ITypeOf` will work as well. I actually tried calling the decorator with two generic parameters manually (ie `decorate(Foo)`), and even though type constraints are enforced, `I` would get inferred to the smallest possible type (ie `{}` if no constraint is applied) so that prompted me to decide to remove it.

Comment: `ITypeOf` as defined in the question is pretty universal and is better known as `type Constructor<T>=...`, [introduced for example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#putting-all-of-the-above-rules-together-in-an-example). If you have several different decorators, each requiring its own restrictions, two parameter approach allows you to declare restrictions in-place together with decorator definition. Restricting argument to `ITypeOf` will require additional interface definition for every kind of restriction. Not much difference though,I agree.